# Problems with reinstallation of SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to reinstall SQL Server 2008. I keep getting the following error:

> The specified directory, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\", parameter is not valid because this directory is compressed or is in a compressed directory.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear here. Remove the compression on the above path.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not work with compressed folders. Please go until the folder, right click on it and make sure the option below is NOT marked: Compress Content to Save Space.

After that, your setup should go smooth.

[image: embedded image]

Answer (score 0):

1 - Go to the Properties of that folder.
2 - Click Advanced.
3 - Untick Compress contents to save disk space.
4 - Click Apply changes to this folder, sub folders and files. 
5 - Click Ok.

[https://fossbytes.com/how-to-compress-drive-to-save-disk-space-using-ntfs-compression]